C# creating API and ASP.NET MVC web app - need help to get warning entering wrong parameters
I'm creating an ASP.NET Web API and MVC web app with SQL Server. It is working well, authorization is successful, but while I'm testing the login screen, if I enter something wrong like a wrong password, it is not returning a warning.
Here is my AccountController's login code
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:7180/api/auth/login", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var tokenResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(tokenResponse);

            if (HttpContext.Session != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("JWToken", token.Token);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Session has not been configured.");
                return View(model);
            }

            TempData["Token"] = token.Token;
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre 
               hatalı.");
            ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre 
               hatalı.";
        }
        
    }

    return View(model);
}

And my login.cshtml view:
@page
@model WebApplication2.Models.LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}
<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SOYADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SOYADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.KULLANICI_ADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KULLANICI_ADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SIFRE)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.SIFRE, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

    @if (ViewData != null && ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(""))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3" role="alert">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    }
        
}
@if (TempData["Token"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success mt-3" role="alert">
        Bearer Token:
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="toggleToken">Toggle Token</button>
        <div id="tokenContent" style="display: none;">
            <pre>@TempData["Token"]</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><p><a href="GetUsers">getallusers</a></p></div>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#toggleToken').click(function () {
                $('#tokenContent').slideToggle();
            });
        });
        
    </script>
}

I am expecting while entering the wrong name, surname, username or password or everything I want to see a warning about them...
Thanks a lot


Add return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); after successful login to navigate to the homepage.
Remove ViewData["ErrorMessage"] since you're already using ModelState.AddModelError to handle errors.
Move the @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) inside a div to always display error messages.


@Vishvadeepsingh Thanks your steps solve my problem. :)

Add a validation summary method at the top of form fields to display all the errors at top or add the Validation message method under each form field to display the default errors under each form field. You can also use Jquery based client-side form validator if you want to validate input errors before hitting to server. Here how you display the errors in the HTML side i.e.
In your CSHTML Add Validation Summary at Top:
... 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <hr />  
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  
   <hr /> 

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SOYADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SOYADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.KULLANICI_ADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KULLANICI_ADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SIFRE)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.SIFRE, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
}

...

OR
In your CSHTML Add Validation Message for Each Field:
... 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ADI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SOYADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SOYADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SOYADI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.KULLANICI_ADI)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KULLANICI_ADI, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.KULLANICI_ADI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SIFRE)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.SIFRE, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SIFRE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
}

...

